# Make clicking a div link to a route or path (Rails 3)

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I understand how to make a div click-able to a specific URL (i.e. "http://example.com"), and am searching for a way to make an entire div click-able, linking to a specific path (i.e. user_path(user), :remote => true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
<%= link_to user_path(user), :remote => true do %>
<div class="divname"></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic answer:

Make your link something like "/users/1" to view the user with a primary key of 1.